# renderer didUpdate for node function in ARKit not being executed

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I was trying to run the following code in XCode:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    // Checking if the planeAnchor exists
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    // Declaring some variables for future use
    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    //The plane(geometry) for the node
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    // The planeNode for the plane anchor
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    //Setting up the plane node
    planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    // Some variables for future use
    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    // The plane node's position
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    // This is done so that the plane node is horizontal
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    // Adding the planeNode to the rootNode??
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    // Informing the user that a plane anchor has been found
    mainLabel.text = "Found a plane anchor!"

}
```

and here's the code of the viewDidLoad function:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
    view.addSubview(sceneView)
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    //Setup constraints
    setupConstraints()
}
```

For some reason, the renderer didUpdate node forAnchor function is not being executed. The mainLabel's text doesn't change at all and the plane is never added in the view. The class is public. What can be the reason for it? How can I fix it?
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you ran the session before completely setting up the configuration. Any session configuration code should be done before running the session. Try this:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {

    sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]

    view.addSubview(sceneView)

    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.delegate = self

    // setup the plane detection FIRST
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // then run the session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)

    //Setup constraints
    setupConstraints()
}
```